# Get Hashmap item from custom adapter

Tags: android, hashmap, custom-adapter, simpleadapter

May i know how to get HashMap item from a custom adapter

Code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feeds_List;
...
...
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put("username", usr_name);
                                map.put("datetime", feed_date);
                                map.put("pts", point_txt);
                                map.put("pic", pic);
                            // adding HashList to ArrayList

                            feeds_List.add(map);

ListAdapter adapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), feeds_List,
                                R.layout.feed_item, new String[]{"username", "datetime", "pts"},
                                new int[]{R.id.usr_name, R.id.feed_time, R.id.no_stamp});
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
      Context context2;

    public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int     resource, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        context2=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if(img == null){
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.usr_pic);
            v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
        }
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String TAG_IMAGE="pic";
        String url =  ((Map)getItem(position)).get("pic");




        // do Picasso
        // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start

        Picasso.with(context2)
                .load(url)
                //.resize(100, 100)
                .into(img);

        // return the view

        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

I cannot get the url string in the custom adapter.
always getting errors of

"Incompatible types"(needed String, but found is object)

for this line

> ```
>     String url =  ((Map)getItem(position)).get("pic");
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you are casting against, should have the exact type. Casting to the generic Map doesn't enforce the compile time check, that the generics are meant for.

```
String url =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("pic");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data;

Map<String, String> category = new Map<String, String>();
    category = data.get(position);
    String url=category.get("pic");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this

```
 String url =  ((Map)getItem(position)).get("pic");
```

to

```
 String url =  list.get(position).get("pic");
```

Also here

```
 Context context2;
 List<HashMap<String, String>> list;
 public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int     resource, String[] from, int[] to){
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    context2=context;
    this.list = data;
 }
```